# Using ajax to display what is being selected not working, PHP, AJAX, JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Using ajax, I'm trying to display what is being selected, but it's not displaying anything at all for some reason. I know the ajax function itself got called, by using alert inside the function, and I think the real problem is actually in test2.php, but I'm not sure what I did wrong. Please take a look:

> test1.php

```
<?php

include('ajax.php');

echo "<select name = 'select' onchange = 'ajax(\"test2.php\",\"output\")'>";

echo "<option value = '1'> 1 </option>";
echo "<option value = '2'> 2 </option>";
echo "<option value = '3'> 3 </option>";

echo "</select>";
echo "<div id = 'output'/>";

?>
```

> test2

```
<?php

$select = $_POST['select'];
echo $select;

?>
```

> ajax.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function ajax(url,id) {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
           }

      });

}

</script>
```

Comment: you are not sending data.`data:  somedata,`

Comment: @NullPoiиteя How do I get it to display something?

Comment: You need to send the data with the ajax request. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ Something like `data: { select: $('select[name="select"]').val()}` in `$.ajax({` See jquery doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not post data to `test2`!!

```
<?php

include('ajax.php');

echo "<select id = 'select' onchange = 'ajax(\"test2.php\",\"output\")'>";

echo "<option value = '1'> 1 </option>";
echo "<option value = '2'> 2 </option>";
echo "<option value = '3'> 3 </option>";

echo "</select>";
echo "<div id = 'output'/>";

?>

function ajax(url,id) {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data : {select:$('#select').find("option:selected").val()}, 
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
           }

      });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing data attribute in Ajax request.

Its a bad practice to mix php scripts and html together. Always think about separation of concern.

Here is how you should do it.

```
<?php 
include('ajax.php');
?>
<select name = 'select'>"
    <option value = '1'> 1 </option>
    <option value = '2'> 2 </option>
    <option value = '3'> 3 </option>
</select>
<div id = 'output'/>
```

Ajax.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change','select',function () {
        var data = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "test2.php",
           data: data,
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(response) {
               $("#output").html(response);
           }

        });
    });

});
</script>
```